# getdeletecommand doesn't delete anything

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sqldataadapter

i'm trying to delete a row in the database with GetDeleteCommand() and DataAdapter.Update().

with GetInsertCommand() and GetUpdateCommand() the all transactions works, but with GetDeleteCommand() fails, i mean, "run" onto this instruction but the data still remains in the table.

here is my code:

```
Public Function delete(ByVal tabla As String, ByVal arg As VariantType) As Boolean
    Dim ok As Boolean = False
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet(tabla)
    Dim dataRow As DataRow
    Dim dataTable As DataTable
    Me.sqlComm.Connection = Me.sqlConn
    Me.sqlComm.CommandText = "Select * from " & tabla

    Try
        Me.sqlDA.SelectCommand = Me.sqlComm
        'llenar el dataset con los datos de la consulta
        Me.sqlDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
        Me.sqlDA.Fill(dataSet, tabla)

        'nuevo commandbuilder
        Me.sqlCB = New SqlCommandBuilder(Me.sqlDA)
        'crear el buffer de la tabla
        dataTable = dataSet.Tables(tabla)
        'buscar el valor en la tabla
        dataRow = dataTable.Rows.Find(arg)
        'obtener el delete command 
        Me.sqlDA.DeleteCommand = Me.sqlCB.GetDeleteCommand(True)
        'actualizar los registros.
        'se supone q con el DeleteCommand deberia borrar en este punto el dato
        Me.sqlDA.Update(dataSet, tabla)

        ok = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString() & vbCrLf & ex.Message())
        Me.err = ex.StackTrace.ToString() & vbCrLf & ex.Message()
    End Try
    Me.sqlConn.Close()
    Return ok
End Function
```

as said before, the all code run without errors, but the data found and "deleted" from my code still remain in the table.

what's wrong? or how to do a correct command or how to do this works?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually deleting the row. You find it, but don't do anything with it after it is found. If you call dataRow.Delete() before your sqlData.Update statement, the row should be deleted.

Comment: yeah... that's right, but then the sqlcommand.getdeletecommand wouldn't be needed as using datarow.delete()